# TSLint: Absolute import before relative

Tags: typescript, tslint

How to throw an error if `relative imports` are declared before `absolute imports` in a `typescript` file.

I looked at the doc of `ordered-imports` but couldn't really get my head around it. I also don't want to enforce the `alphabetical order` rule

Comment: I think the alphabetical order rule is activated by default, this what `ordered-imports` is for. I don't know if there is a rule to put relative import after absolute though.

Comment: Yes. That is not what I am looking for. But a rule that allows to separate absolute and relative imports

Comment: My bad, I read you question too fast. I think you will need another tool (eg. eslint) to enforce such import order. A quick search leads me to https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/first.md